# Calculate limiting molar conductivity of BaCl2

Tags: concentration, conductivity

How can I calculate limiting molar conductivity of BaCl<sub>2</sub> in water at 25 degree Celsius?

I have got a formula for calculating limiting molar conductivity .

> limiting molar conductivity  =  V<sub>+</sub> A<sub>+</sub> +
> V<sub>-</sub> A<sub>-</sub>
>
> V<sub>+</sub>  =  number of cations per formula unit of the
> electrolyte
>
> V<sub>-</sub>  =  number of anions per formula unit of the
> electrolyte
>
> A<sub>+</sub> = molar conductivity of the cations
>
> A<sub>-</sub> = molar conductivity of the anions

Here I figured out, V<sub>+</sub> = 1 and V<sub>-</sub> = 2
How can I solve the question and tell me  if there is any information that is not present above to solve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer the second part of your question first: you have one equation with three unknowns, so you need the value's of two more unknowns, namely the molar conductivities of Ca++ and Cl-.  They are readily available from the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics.  Every chemist and chemistry prof and library has one.  You could also find those values from online resources, just be sure to check with reliable sources.  An internet search will turn up many.  Once you have those two values you just plug them in to your equation and you are done.  You are correct with your V values.